# Blender 2.8 EEVEE render out viewport like old openGL render

Tags: rendering, opengl, eevee-render-engine

In the older versions of blender 2.8 it used to be possible (I did it once and I saw videos of people doing it) to render out the viewport (I think it was with an OpenGL render option), in rendered mode with EEVEE and it gives an, albeit lower quality than the final EEVEE render product, a function EEVEE-level real-time render of the scene from the viewport.

In the newer versions of blender 2.8 I noticed this option has been removed and I can't seem to find it (or anything about it on the web)! Does anyone HOW to still accomplish this functionality? It's probably just some built in function whose button was removed, but the function probably still exists... does anyone know how to access it with python, or do I need to make my own build of blender? If I need to make my own build to get the function back, does anyone at least know the C++ function to call to get it???

Answer (score 10):

In the 3D View header menu go to *View > Viewport Render*

Answer (score 4):

There are two feasible options.

A. view -> viewport render with eevee (see Image 2 "A") . This produces a lower quality and faster eevee render directly from the viewport. On the other hand this is not as fast as openGL Render in 2.79.

[image]

B. Go to Workbench Renderer (see Image 2 "B") and do the same: view -> viewport Render. This Renders a version without textures and without actual lighting. Id say that this is the fastest way, for example checking if the animated motion etc. is smooth or for other test-renders.

[image]

Both: There are various settings in regards to the overlay or you could simply disable all overlays at once:
[image]

Also both Renders have various settings of course, but for quick renders workbenchs options as for example matcap would be of most interest:
[image]

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work, since i need a real time render at. 1920x1080, do you have any script code?

Comment: Can you explain your usecase a little bit further? is the focus on realtime? resolution shouldnt be a problem as the viewport render resolution is specified by the output properties.

Comment: and what kind of script code do you mean?

Comment: a python script to capture the screen in realtime https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/128174/python-get-image-of-3d-view-for-streaming-realtime-eevee-rendering

Comment: can you specify what the problem ist with render viewport or the advantage of screenshoting via python? out of interest :)

Comment: Like everything, viewport render is NOT at all real time, it took me 6 hours to render a 5 minute video, that is ridiculous, it wasn't even a high poly or complicated scene, just a couple low low poly skinned meshes with the new pdsf or something shader, it plays in real time in eevee when i play in the timeline, there's absolutely no reason at all it shouldn't be able to save in real time, which viewport render absolutely dues not do

Answer (score 3):

Try changing the render engine to Workbench. Then below that in the Lighting tab, and Color tab, you can change the viewport settings. Then you can render it and it will render the viewport.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi thanks, I tried switching to workbench but now everything is gray.. do you mind showing a couple screenshots of what you did to retain your node materials in the workbench renderer?

Comment: Sorry, I tired to figure that out but I don't know how to do that. The only things I can figure out how to change are the Flat, Studio, or Matcap Lighting.