# Why my render doesnt reflect the color and properties of my shaders applied to the object?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, texturing

[image: What I want in the Render image, that is the Viewport Shading]

[image: And this is the effect on the final render image]

The bronze effect is with the help of quixel textures and there is an HDR image in the background. How do I preserve those effects and bronze texture in a render animation or image?

I'm using the shader mode and I have checked the transparency also, in the film section of the render properties. For the Render, I´m using Cycles with CPU toggled on.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/170533/which-mode-should-i-trust-for-lighting

Comment: So basically I cannot render the HDRI effects on the Drill bit? Because I don't want the preview mode, I want that this can be reflected on my final render or animation.

Comment: You can, you just have to set it up beforehand, *Material Preview Mode* doesn't necessarily represent final render. You can also [render the viewport](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/127240/blender-2-8-eevee-render-out-viewport-like-old-opengl-render)

Comment: Ok so it rendered the animation on material preview, but it didn't worked with the viewport shading: rendered. Like, makes my object invisible and moving, of course, any idea of what is going on? Thank you for the help :)